# Java Process killed by windows with event id 593

Tags: java, windows

I am using Jboss as an Application Server for deployment of my enterprise application. It's running fine for months but suddenly "Java" process is killed by windows with event id 593. That means process is killed. We are using JDK 1.5_u12. In windows we didn't get any logs why process is killed. Is there any option available in JDK 1.5_u12 to log anything or dump when any java process is killed or crashed.

With regards,
Avinash Nigam

Answer (score 0):

you can check the jboss server log file at standalone/log/server.log